# Mute HTML5 video on subsequent visit

Tags: javascript, html, video, modal-dialog, mute

I am using Reveal Modal (http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin) to fire off a modal pop-up box on the visitor's first visit *only*, setting a cookie using jQuery Cookie (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

Here is the code for the modal (shows a GIF on mobile devices):

```
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var isMobile = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/);
    var myModal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    if(!isMobile) {
    // User-Agent is not IPhone, IPod, IPad, Android or BlackBerry
    myModal.innerHTML += '<video autoplay>' +
    '<source src="video/LogoOpening.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>' +
    '<source src="video/LogoOpening.ogg" type="video/ogg"/>' +
    '<source src="video/LogoOpening.webm" type="video/webm"/>' +
    '</video>' +
    '<a class="close-reveal-modal"><div class="button4">Close</div></a>';
    } else {
    myModal.innerHTML += '<img src="images/ThroughTheYears.gif" alt="Logo History" />' +
    '<a class="close-reveal-modal"><div class="button4">Close</div></a>' +
    '</div>';
    }
</script>
```

...and here is the Javascript that fires off the modal after checking for the cookie:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    if ($.cookie('modal_shown') == null) {
        $.cookie('modal_shown', 'yes', { expires: 30, path: '/' });
        $('#myModal').reveal({
         animation: 'fade',                         //fade, fadeAndPop, none
         animationspeed: 500,                       //how fast animtions are
         closeonbackgroundclick: true,              //if you click background will modal close?
         dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal'    //the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
         });
    }
    });
</script>
```

**So, here's the issue:** when my visitor shows up the first time, the video fires off perfectly and plays automatically, just like it should *(a similar animated GIF plays on mobile devices only)*; however, the video has sound, and on subsequent visits the video autoplays and you *hear* the audio, but the modal doesn't *visually* fire off (the modal and video stays hidden).

I think the solution would be to somehow tie the video's mute attribute to the cookie checking Javascript (which determines whether the modal fires or not), but I'm not sure how to code that. **Help?**

Comment: could you not check for `$.cookie('modal_shown') == null` in the first section of JS and if not set the video to autoplay, but if it has been shown then don't set the `autoplay` and/or add the `muted` property

Comment: That sounds like a great idea...now how would I code it? (Keep in mind that I didn't write the Javascript above by hand, so I'm not very strong in the JS department.)   :\

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work

```
if (!isMobile) {
    // User-Agent is not IPhone, IPod, IPad, Android or BlackBerry
    if ($.cookie('modal_shown') == null) {
        myModal.innerHTML += '<video autoplay controls>'
    } else {
        myModal.innerHTML += '<video autoplay muted controls>'
    }
    myModal.innerHTML += '<source src="video/LogoOpening.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>' +
    ....
    ....
    '</video>' +
```

... adding the extra check for the cookie `model_shown` allows you to change if the video will autoplay, or will autoplay but be muted (if you would prefer it not to autoplay you could remove that, in which case the muted may also not be needed. I also added the `controls` so the user can control volume or play/pause manually if desired

hope this helps (if not quite what you need just comment and I'll try and get closer)

Comment: Thanks for your willingness to help! I put the updated code here: http://jsfiddle.net/4jQZe/

Have a look and see where I'm going wrong, as the code isn't working. I need to keep the GIF statement in there for mobile devices, but I'm not sure the JS is written correctly to support that.